# Set cookie path using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, cookies

In my (remote) server, for cookies default `path` is given as not `/`. I need that path will `/`.

Of course I can set path at at creating cookies so:

```
  setcookie("name", "value" ,time() + 3600, "/");
```

but I interest, how can set default cookies path via `.htaccess` file ?

Comment: The default cookie path is the directory the cookie is set in. I can't see a way how that could be changed using a .htaccess file.

Comment: Me neither, I don't think .htaccess supports that. The closest solution is to set it in your php.ini

Comment: Ok, understand. I need that create cookie without expire time, but set path as `/`. what value must be set as expire parameter in this case? just `time()`? or ?

Answer (score 1):

This parameter of php.ini is:

```
session.cookie_path
```

So, inside an htaccess file you could do:

```
php_value session.cookie_path yourpath
```

You could also use the php function `session_set_cookie_params()` but it is probably a bit heavy for what you need.

Comment: very helpful answer